# Dot net Blogging Engine that supports workflows? (Like MOSS)

Tags: asp.net, blogging

Is there a Dot Net Blogging Engine that supports worflows.

What I need is a way to automatically send an email to an editor when a new post is written, then once the post is edited, the author has to authorize that the editor didn't change the content of the message. Only then can the post be published. (kinda like MOSS supports)

Is there a blog engine that supports (or partialy supports) this type of feature.

Answer (score 2):

Have you checked out [Dot Net Nuke](http://www.dotnetnuke.com/Community/Blogs/tabid/825/EntryId/2284/DotNetNuke-5-1-0-Released.aspx).  The first item under "Major Highlights" is this:

> Added Content Versioning and simple workflow to the HTML module